# Transparent PNG imagemagick passthru

Tags: php, imagemagick, transparency

I have this code. It should crate a transparent PNG, but its output is black backgrounded PNG instead. On CentOS.

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
passthru("convert -background transparent -fill red -pointsize 72 -font TR.Matisse.ITC.TTF -gravity Center label:'Font Test' png:-");
?>
```

this works flawlessly on ubuntu terminal:

```
convert -background transparent -fill red -pointsize 72 -font TR.Matisse.ITC.TTF -gravity Center label:'Font Test' png.png
```

So how do I get it to be transparent (and not have a black matte) by calling the system command from PHP?

Comment: The two command strings end differently. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @vascowhite. No the 'passthru' command gives the result directly to php. Terminal command just creates and saves the png.

Comment: To trouble shoot this I would strip that command down to the bare minimum that will do something I can see. Once that is working add other functionality one item at a time. I'm not familiar with what you are trying to do, but that's how I would do it.

Comment: I tried to much things. Nothing worked.

Comment: Black Matte *or* Transparent? You need to make a decision.

Comment: i want background transparent but code creates a black one

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the proper transparent command for ImageMagick this:

```
convert -transparent <SomeColor> -fill red -pointsize 72 -font TR.Matisse.ITC.TTF -gravity Center label:'Font Test' png.png
```

Or else use an Alpha channel:

```
convert -alpha transparent -fill red -pointsize 72 -font TR.Matisse.ITC.TTF -gravity Center label:'Font Test' png.png
```

Comment: well in command line `convert -background transparent -fill red -pointsize 72 -gravity Center label:"Font Test" C:\wamp\www\xxyyzz.png`  

works but not in php

Comment: Yes but does that command work in the command line of the CentOS server or just Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try using exec() and saving the file to disk then see if it is the correct image. You may find the issue is with php and the passthru.